# How to load data when it's first needed and keep it to use in other places

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular SPA, there's some data loaded from the backend that is used throughout the application. This data doesn't change while the app is in use, so to keep things slick for the users I'd like to only load this data once. I can see two possible solutions here:

Load the data when the app is first initialised and attaching it to `$rootScope` using `angular.module.run()`

or

The first controller to need the data loads it, and then puts it... *somewhere*... where everything else can get to it.

Which approach is the "most Angular" way to do this, and how would I start to implement it? Most of the questions on SO seem to be about loading data with the controller rather than when the app itself starts. I'm using 1.4.7 with UI Router if that makes a difference.

Comment: use a service to load and manage your data (services are singletons), and use the `resolve` parameter on the routes to ensure the data is available when the route is navigated to.  **don't** use `$rootScope` for this kind of logic.

Comment: Yes, but If I have a controller for each page, won't the data get reloaded every time the user moves to a different page?

Comment: I did offer my opinion here, but I still marked the question as "too broad".  It could just as easily be marked as "Primarily Opinion Based", since there is really no right or wrong answer, and multiple people will have different opinions on "the right way".  You should consider asking this from the perspective of "I tried it this way and I had these problems", rather than "what would other people do".

Comment: no, again, services are singletons.  The `resolve` property also understands promises, so you can simply point to the data on the service, and if the data doesn't exist, have the service make a promise through `$http` or other means to retrieve the data.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I phrased the question the way I did as I expected that there would be more than one way to do this and that at least some of the answers would be horrible hacks which I was trying prematurely to filter out!

Comment: I guess I should have phrased it "I don't know how to do this thing and the way I've thought of doesn't feel right". I'm still getting used to Angular's feature set, so I genuinely wasn't aware that's how `resolve` could be used.

Comment: using `resolve` is not strictly necessary; you could inject the service directly into the controller.  The main purpose for using `resolve` is to ensure that the data is available **before** the controller is instantiated, meaning that you can write controllers that consistently have data, not controllers that have to fetch data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a service which has been sugested by others and ALSO make the service load the data in a lazy way. (Lazy loading pattern described here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)